# What is Rails Way? (readability vs drying)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User model, which have voting methods. I want to write proxy methods for voting.

This is readable way:

```
def vote_up item
  return false unless can? :vote, item
  vote item, :up
end

def vote_down item
  return false unless can? :vote, item
  vote item, :down
end
```

And this is DRY way:

```
%w(up down).each do |vtype|
  define_method "vote_#{vtype}" do |item|
    return false unless can? :vote, item
    vote item, vtype.to_sym
  end
end
```

Which one is better and why?

Comment: Personally, considering you only have 2 methods here, and it's unlikely you'd ever add more (vote_sideways? vote_diagonally?) I would just go with the readable way. If you could potentially have many, many more though, I would go with the DRY way (because it becomes easily extendible) with a readable comment to explain to other developers (or to yourself later!).

Comment: Agree with @MrDanA --- another question: do you want to use this in more classes than just this "item" ?

Comment: atm MrDanA's answer is better. ty!

Comment: Jesse Wolgamott, four in total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Purely because OP seemed to like my comment, I'll put it as an answer:

Personally, considering you only have 2 methods here, and it's unlikely you'd ever add more (vote_sideways? vote_diagonally?) I would just go with the readable way. If you could potentially have many, many more though, I would go with the DRY way (because it becomes easily extendible) with a readable comment to explain to other developers (or to yourself later!).

Answer (score 2):

Neither(sorry).

```
def vote_count(item,vtype)
  return false unless can? :vote, item
  vote item, vtype
end
```

Good luck

Comment: People often forget that you can pass more than one parameter to a method.

Comment: in my case i get recursion here

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, in this case, readability trumps dry. It scans quickly, and is easily grokked. Having said that, if you start adding vote types the second approach may be more flexible. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Both.

I'm with Anil; just pass in a type--meta-programming this as a first-resort is yucky.

That said, I *am* a fan of convenience methods--but they should call the generic method with the type.

This keeps the generated method concise--the real work is done in the generic method, but the API user still gets the same convenience methods.